# android restore instance state of a fragment that is in backstack

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

Hi I have an activity that has two fragments.

1. Fragment A
2. Fragment B

   - Fragment A has an EditText and a ListView.
   - Once I enter something in the EditText and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I populate the ListView.
   - Now Fragment A's ListView is populated with data.
   - Clicking any item on the ListView of fragment A will send the user to fragment   B
   - At this point I am replacing fragment A with fragment B
   - So when the user hits back button he comes back to fragment A

Now the problem is if the user is in fragment B and config changes occur like screen rotation etc more than once then my that my ListView is empty because my arraylist is null.

Note that I am using onSavedInstanceState in fragment A and fragment B. 
If my current fragment is  fragment A and config changes occur then there is no problem of restoring the state since in onCreateView I am getting the arraylist from bundle.

I know the reason why my arraylist is null when I comeback from fragment B to fragment A which is in backstack previously.When fragment A is in backstack the only method that is being called is onSaveInstanceState so after the first config change my arraylist field is null as I couldnt assign my arraylist stored in savedInstateState bundle to the arraylist field.

I do not want to use android:configchanges attribute in my manifest.

My Question is how can I restore the state of a fragment that is in backstack.

Comment: Just store your arralist in `onSavedInstance()` method. Then check on `onCreateView()` method if `onSavedInstance` will not be null then just retrieve your arraylist.

Comment: It does not work in my case.  Your stated method  works to saveState when device orientation changes but my problem is coming back from fragment B

Comment: When you back your `onStart()` first call so check if your arraylist will not be null then set your adapter.

Comment: Thank you @PiyushGupta your hint helped me coming back from fragment B I checked if my arrayList in fragment A is null or not. If its not null I am populating my listview again.

Comment: @PiyushGupta but there is still another problem when I rotate the phone twice while in fragment B the arrayList in fragment A is becoming null

Comment: In your manifest file for ur activity use ConfigChanges = "screenSize|keyBoardHidden|orientation"

Comment: This will prevent to reload your data when your configuration changes. And fragment is the part of activity so we can't register it in manifest file. So we need to apply that permission to particular activity which creates a fragments !!

Comment: Yup I googled it and read a stackoverflow answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I achieved the goal of retaining the state of fragment which is in  backstack by passing all the details of that fragment to main activity before it is added to backstack and saving the state in main activity's savedInstance state and whenever backstack changes and previous fragment is visible I am passing the saved instance state of that fragment to it from main activity and this way I am retaining the state. I am not sure if this the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through your scenario. 
Basically you are doing right job when you are adding arraylist in savedinstanceState of your fragment but according to me you are doing little mistake in your activity.

As when orientation changes Activity call onDestroy then onCreate in that scenario if you are not checking that either your fragment is already added or not then it will replace it with new one.
Here is code you should put in onCreate()

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("FragmentA");
    if(fragment==null){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new FrgamentA(), "FragmentA").commit();
    }
```

Another point is when you want your first fragment to be retained add

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

in onCreate of fragment.

Please find this demo at GitHub
[inpulse-fragment](https://github.com/ankur-rise/impulse-fragment)

In this demo at first fragment when you will increase the counter it'll appear in text view above and if you click on that text view you will be navigate to Fragment B. Now you can try rotating. 
Let me know in case of any query.

Comment: setRetainInstance(true); It doesnt work for me since I want the fragment to be recreated again and using setRetainInstance(true) the fragment wont be recreated again. Also I have similar code of adding fragment in onCreate of my MainActivity. I kind of solved the problem by saving state of backstack fragment in the mainactivity.Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setRetaininstance(true)` in `onAttach` and this line
`ConfigChanges = "screenSize|keyBoardHidden|orientation"` in activity manifest file.

Comment: Vikram I mentioned in the question that I do not want to stop the activity to recreate itself when config changes. So using ConfigChanges won't achieve the goal